# RestTemplate exchange call return result in XML format

Tags: spring-boot, spring-resttemplate

We have two Microservice Services1 and Service2.
In Service1 we have one PostMapping and return boolean value as below.

```
@PostMapping
public boolean reset(){
    return true
}
```

When consume from Service2 through restTemplate exchange method it will return in XML format as below.

```
boolean val = restTemplate.exchange(url, Post method, http entity with header, Boolean.class);
```

Output

```
<boolean>true</boolean>
```

**we expecting in JSON format in resttemplate call and if try through postman it will return in JSON.**

Comment: Depending on the service that you’re calling, you may need to include an `Accept` header in the request to indicate that you want to receive json. Have you set one in your request?

Comment: If I add that I got 415 media not support error.

Comment: That’s odd. What media type did you use? I’d check the headers of the request that Postman is sending, and adjust your code that’s using RestTemplate to match.